# js cookie to remember if div has been shown already

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have the following line of code on document ready:

```
HB.BestBreakfast.showPanelAndHideOthers("commentBox");
```

however every time I refresh the page the div.commentBox is always displaying. 
How can I use a cookie to make the '.commentBox' only display the first time the document has loaded? and if you refresh the page it should stay hidden...

Comment: What is `HB.BestBreakfast`?

Comment: Can you give us some more code ( html, js, ... ) so we can see what you are trying todo

Answer (score 0):

use jquery cookie plugin to set and read cookie
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

set cookie if not available i.e. the page loads for first time
if cookie exists, then hide the div

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the code you wrote. But you can use following snippet:

```
 if ($.cookie('commentBox')) $('.commentBox').hide();
 else {
     $.cookie('commentBox', true);    
 }
```